# How does airside transit work at the Düsseldorf and Berlin-Tegel airports?

Tags: transit, airports, germany, dus, txl

According to Timatic, the database used by airlines, in order to transit Düsseldorf or Berlin-Tegel airport in Germany airside, i.e. without clearing immigration, the airport authorities must be notified in advance by the airline.

I understand this is due to these airports lacking transit corridors ([looking at this map of Düsseldorf](https://www.dus.com/~/media/fdg/dus_com/reisende/fluege/umsteigen/haeder%20images/transfer-de_970px.jpg?h=541&la=de-DE&w=970), non-Schengen lounges are in dark blue, separated from one another by Schengen lounges)

So how is the connection actually organised at these airports? What happens once you land?

Comment: I once read (about Berlin-Tegel) that passengers needed an escort from the police and that was why the airline had to be notified to arrange it. Presumably, that means there is a police officer walking with you from one gate to the next or possibly to a waiting area. Never saw it first hand so I will let someone else confirm or correct that.

Comment: I have asked TXL in German on Twitter. Will post an answer when they reply.

Comment: @simbabque They replied that you should contact the border police. Gonna do it myself and post their answer. Thanks!

Comment: I have seen. That. I figured waiting since the police had been mentioned would work. ;-)

Comment: They said the airline takes care of it in TXL because there is no transit zone. I asked for more specific information and referenced this question, but they never replied to that.

Comment: @simbabque I know Tegel has a peculiar layout, with the security checks being performed at the entrance to each gate rather than at the entrance to a larger gate area. Before security, there's a passport control booth, which is manned when a non-Schengen flight is leaving from that gate.

Comment: I asked at the Lufthansa check in booth at TXL. They said the airline takes you to a special holding room until the international connection is ready. I joked that it's probably a dark room in the basement. He said it is in the basement indeed. The police is not involved at all.

Comment: @simbabque Wow, thanks for taking the time to go over there (I've done that too, but still). WHy not make this an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to a comment by @simbaque:

> I asked at the Lufthansa check in booth at TXL. They said the airline takes you to a special holding room until the international connection is ready. I joked that it's probably a dark room in the basement. He said it is in the basement indeed. The police is not involved at all.